# RAID5 now showing as two virtual disks instead of one

Tags: raid

We have an old PE2950 that was just about to be decommissioned and were told that nothing of importance was on it.  After a power failure the other day it came up saying that the RAID array was a foreign config.  Attempting to import the foreign configuration shows it as two RAID5 volumes with only one disk in each and two missing disks.

So, two disks are still online, I should be able to access the last bit of information on it, but it is showing as two VDs instead of one.  It thinks that it has two different RAID5 volumes each missing two disks, instead of a single RAID5 volume with one failed disk.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction to fix this?  It seems odd that the metadata would have survived enough to tell the controller that there is a RAID VD, but be corrupted enough to show it as two distinct VDs instead of the one that it was before.

Answer (score 0):

appears some one try to recreate RAID5 previously, so he created another one RAID. If both VD appears degraded its very difficult recover the information. You say only 2 disk are online, maybe 1 per VM/RAID. For me, this content was lost.

Regards!